# В чём ошибка в словах "не осмысленна" и "небезынтересна"?

Tags: частица-не, прилагательные, причастия

> 1. Путешественник, ученый, писатель Владимир Арсеньев оставил огромное наследие, часть которого, как ни странно, не осмысленна до сих пор, имею в виду прежде всего дневники и письма.
> 2. Составлял геополитические прогнозы, часть из которых сбылась уже после его смерти, а часть небезынтересна и поныне, помогал царской и советской властям заселять и развивать дальневосточные периферии.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка в словах "не осмысленна" и "небезынтересна"? Укажите, что это за части речи, как правильно написать эти слова, почему?

Answer (score 0):

1. `(не) осмысле(н, нн)а` - это *причастие*. Точнее краткое причастие. То есть:

   - Оно пишется **раздельно** с частицей `не`: `не осмысле(н, нн)а`.
   - Оно пишется с **одной** `н`: `не осмыслена`.
2. `(не)безынтересна` - это *прилагательное*.

   - Оно пишется **слитно** с `не`, так как к нему можно подобрать синоним без не (любопытно, занятно). Спасибо @Nadezhda, что поправила меня: ведь краткие прилагательные пишутся так же, как и прилагательные в полной форме. Но  стоит заметить, что в качестве синонима без не к слову `небезынтересна` слово `интересно` для определения написания `не` (слитно/раздельно) не подходит, так как это слово однокоренное.

Comment: Не согласна с тем, что краткое прилагательное нужно писать раздельно с не. Нет такого правила, и вообще в данном случае следует писать слитно. Можно заменить на синоним - интересна.

Comment: @Nadezhda с краткими прилагательными я действительно погорячился, но брать слово "интересна" как синоним нельзя, так как это слово однокоренное

Comment: @Nadezhda спасибо, что заметили ошибку, исправил ответ.